# The method parse(FileReader) is undefined for the type JSONParser

Tags: java

I have problem in my java class when I try to read from json file 
it;s show me this error :
Note : I installed json-simple and use it succeufuly

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      The method parse(FileReader) is undefined for the type
>   JSONParser
>
> at com.cd.JSONParser.main(JSONParser.java:18)

this is my code :

```
    package com.cd;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JSONParser {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

            try {

                Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("g:\\testm1.json"));

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

                String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
                System.out.println(name);

                long age = (Long) jsonObject.get("age");
                System.out.println(age);

                // loop array
                JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("messages");
                Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(iterator.next());
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named your own class the same way as the json-simple `JSONParser` class. So the compiler resolves `JSONParser` to your own class (`com.cd.JSONParser`) and not to the json-simple `JSONParser` (`org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser`).

Rename your class. Or use `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser` instead of `JSONParser` each time you want to refer to this class.

Answer (score 2):

Rename your class to something else than `JSONParser`. This name collides with `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser`, so when you call:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
```

you're actually instantiating your `com.cd.JSONParser` instead of `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser`.

General rule, don't call your classes the same as some library classes that you use (especially JDK classes), unless you really have to. In such case, you can always use the *fully qualified name* such as:

```
org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser parser =
    new org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser();
```